# 10 random rows from excel

Tags: c#, excel, random

Help me with my code, because i don't now how to do this simple task. How to select 10 random rows from excel file?

```
        string filepath = @"C:\1.xlsx";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        showdata.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Can you select the top 10 rows?

Comment: It looks like you're already getting the Excel data into a DataTable, so for the randomization you've removed Excel from the equation.  (Which is good, separation of concerns and all that.)  Have you made any attempt at the randomization yet?  There's a `Random` object which can generate numbers for you.  You could give it the row count and ask it for 10 numbers, which would be row indices.  (You'd have to check for duplicate indices and re-ask for another random number, I assume.  Since true randomness allows for duplicates but it sounds like you don't want that.)

Comment: There must be no dublicates, because in excel table list of people with such columns as name, last name, contacts etc. Share your code variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a DataGridView on your Windows Form called `RandomExcelRows`, create a button called `button1` and put the following code inside the **Click** event handler for `button1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Range[] rows = RandomRows(10, @"C:\test\whatever.xlsx");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    bool ColumnsCreated = false;

    foreach(Excel.Range row in rows)
    {
        object[,] values = row.Value;

        int columnCount = values.Length;

        if(!ColumnsCreated)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(String.Format("Column {0}", i));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                ColumnsCreated = true;
            }
        }

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            dr[String.Format("Column {0}", i)] = values[1,i+1];
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    RandomExcelRows.DataSource = dt;
}
```

And then create a method underneath called **RandomRows** containing the following:

```
private Excel.Range[] RandomRows(int randomRowsToGet, string worksheetLocation, int worksheetNumber = 1, int lowestRow = 0, int highestRow = 99)
{
    Excel.Range[] rows = new Excel.Range[randomRowsToGet];

    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(worksheetLocation);
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[worksheetNumber];

    List<int> rowNumbers = new List<int>();

    bool allUniqueNumbers = false;

    Random random = new Random();

    while (!allUniqueNumbers)
    {
        int nextNumber = random.Next(lowestRow, highestRow);

        if (!rowNumbers.Contains(nextNumber))
            rowNumbers.Add(nextNumber);

        if (rowNumbers.Count == randomRowsToGet)
            allUniqueNumbers = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < randomRowsToGet; i++)
    {
        rows[i] = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows[rowNumbers[i]];
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);

    return rows;
}
```

The program will take a random number of rows (this amount is specified by you) from the Spreadsheet you specify and place these rows into your DataGridView.

It's pretty crude, and needs refactoring but it is the basis of what you need. You could also get the string containing the file location from a textbox instead of hardcoding this, the same goes for the number of rows you want, and the other parameters such as minimum and maximum rows.

As well, you could use an [OpenFileDialog](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog) to allow your user to browse to your excel file, etc etc.

Comment: Wow! Big thanks! How to output this array of Excel.Range objects to DataGridView in winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
        string filepath = @"C:\1.xlsx";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        // above code block is yours as is.
        // below part is for sorting.

        DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
        data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Guid"));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            data.Rows[i].SetField("Guid", Guid.NewGuid());
        }
        DataView dv = data.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "Guid desc";            
        showdata.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
```